# ZIP each file in a directory that doesn't already have a ZIPped version in another folder

Tags: batch-file, command-line, 7zip

I am using 7-zip and Windows 2008 Server and need to ZIP each file in folder `C:\Original` *that doesn't already have a corresponding ZIP file in `C:\Archived`*. I would prefer doing this with a `.bat` file.

The `C:\Original` folder contains a series of `.PDF` files that are never changes, like so:

- MyResume.pdf
- HouseLayout.pdf
- SurveyResults.pdf
- BlahBlahBlah.pdf

I want to run a batch file that will create a ZIP file for each PDF in the `C:\Archive` folder, but only if the file doesn't already exist. For instance, if the `C:\Archive` folder already has two files in it:

- MyResume.zip
- BlahBlahBlah.zip

Running the batch file would ZIP just the two unzipped files, `HouseLayout.pdf` and `SurveyResults.pdf`.

I have a batch file that uses the `FOR` command that will ZIP *all* of the files in `C:\Original`, but I only want to ZIP those that don't already exist in `C:\Archive`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for %%f in ("c:\original\*.pdf") do if not exist "c:\archive\%%~nf.zip" (
    7za a "c:\archive\%%~nf.zip" "%%~ff"
)
```

For each file in the indicated folder/set if not exist a file with the same name but with zip extension, create the zip file with the original file inside it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
for /F %%I in ('dir /b c:\original\*.pdf') do set filename=%%I
set archivedFile=%filename:~,-4%

if not exist C:\archive\%archivedFile%.zip (
  REM zip it up
)
```

Comment: This will process only one file.